# How to chain query scopes in mongoengine

Tags: python, scope, mongoengine, chaining

I have defined query scopes and want to chain them while accessing, but It throws error `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'active'`

Here's my code:

```py
class User(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=120, default=None)
    is_paid = BooleanField(default=True, required=True)
    is_active = BooleanField(default=True, required=True)
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), required=True)

    meta = {
      'collection': 'users'
    }

    @queryset_manager
    def paid(doc_cls, queryset):
      return queryset.filter(is_paid=True)

    @queryset_manager
    def active(doc_cls, queryset):
        return queryset.filter(is_active=True)
```

Now I'm trying to chain the scopes like this:

```py
users = User.paid().active()
print(users)
```

Help me solve this :-)